how to know client date in request in nginx?
I have a web server configured with nginx and I am saving the logs in json format in a file to later display it in a dashboard but I need the time and date of the client at the time it made the request to the server
Is this possible? How can I get it?

Nginx sets two variables that you could add to your logs: $time_iso8601 and $time_local

In the nginx documentation it says "local time", does this refer to the server or the client?

The time stamp originates from the server.
